# Change damped track target for all objects in scene

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I want to make a script wich changes the active camera in scene and the damped track target for all objects with a damped track named "Face Camera".
Therefore I've created 3 scripts. One to switch in side view, one to switch in front view and one for a custom menu to access this options.
Changing the active camera works perfect. But setting the target only effects the selected object.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Front view (Side view works the same):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Switch Camera Front",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy


class SwitchCameraFr(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Switch Camera Front"""
    bl_idname = "object.switchcamfront"
    bl_label = "Switch Camera Front"   
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):   

        bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera.001"]
        for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            try:
                bpy.context.object.constraints["Face Camera"].target = bpy.data.objects["Camera.001"]
            except:
                print ("No Constraint named Face Camera")
        return {'FINISHED'}




def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SwitchCameraFr)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SwitchCameraFr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Menu:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Switch Camera Menu",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy


class SwitchCameraMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    """Switch Camera Menu"""      # blender will use this as a tooltip for menu items and buttons.
    bl_idname = "object.switchcammenu"        # unique identifier for buttons and menu items to reference.
    bl_label = "Switch Camera Menu"         # display name in the interface.
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}  # enable undo for the operator.

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("object.switchcamside")
        layout.operator("object.switchcamfront")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SwitchCameraMenu)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SwitchCameraMenu)


# This allows you to run the script directly from blenders text editor
# to test the add-on without having to install it.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: On first glance suggest: Change `bpy.context.object.constraints["Face Camera"].target = bpy.data.objects["Camera.001"]` to `ob.constraints["Face Camera"].target = context.scene.objects.get("Camera.001")`

Comment: I feel stupid now.
Thank you very much!